# Navigating back to webpage when in a sub folder

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I'm designing a new website and having a few problems navigating back to another page in the root directory when I'm in a sub folder.

Below is how I have got it setup:

index.htm
page1.htm
page2.htm
folder/page1.htm

So when I'm in folder/page1.htm, when I try and click on page2.htm, it thinks it should be in "folder/page2.htm" rather than "website.com/page2.htm" in the root directory.

Now maybe to complicate things more, I have all the links set in a template file with 1 editable region (just the content inside).  So any changes I do the links, are saved for all pages.

Is there anyway I can navigate to the other pages such as page2.htm when I'm in folder/page1.htm?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

add this code at folder/page1.htm

```
<a href='../page2.htm' />Page 2</a>
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks, just tried it and it looks like its worked.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have your links written as absolute paths instead of relative by adding a leading slash that denotes the sites root, so your links would look like:

```
<a href="/index.htm">Index</a>
<a href="/page1.htm">Page 1</a>
<a href="/page2.htm">Page 2</a>
<a href="/folder/page1.htm">Folder page 1</a>
```

now it doesn't matter where on the site your visitor is, `Page 2` will always go to `website.com/page2.htm`